# How can I remove event attributes with datadog/browser-logs?

Tags: logging, datadog

I am using datadog/browser-logs and upon logging it is creating an attribute called config that contains an object data. These attributes seem to be logged automatically. There are properties I do not which to include, how can I remove some properties?

Image below shows section in question which I want to remove properties from

[Datadog event attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Z4g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeSend` to scrub/alter values.

```js
import { datadogLogs } from '@datadog/browser-logs'

datadogLogs.init({
    ...,
    beforeSend: (log) => {
        if (log.message.config)
            delete log.message.config // or whatever property you want to remove
    },
    ...
});
```

but I also suggest trying to understand how the value is getting there in the first place

Comment: I added a screenshot show the event attribute for context. The LogsEvent object uses Typescript and does not allow config property. Config is also not on the log itself thus the reason for not being able to remove it to date.

Comment: You need to establish what the "it" in "it is creating an attribute called config" is now, since you've established it's not browser-logs